# Why is "I believe in woman" ok? Or isn't it? (from Slade's "My Oh My")

Tags: grammatical-number, phonology, phonetics

This first line of the song is *I believe in woman, my oh my*.

I'm not a native speaker, but that sounds odd to me. I'd either expect *women* (*I believe in women* [in general]) or some kind of determiner (*I believe in this/my/a woman*).

I wondered whether the singer might speak some dialect that doesn't differentiate between *woman* and *women* phonetically, but the band's from England and the word is written as *woman* on the various lyrics sites all over the net.

What does this line mean and why is it ok to omit the determiner?

Comment: It's not proper grammar, it seems to have been written that way for stylistic purposes. In general, you shouldn't always expect normal grammar in songs and poetry.

Comment: @Barmar: you have any source for the idea it's not "proper" grammar? One can believe in love, as well as in apple pie or woman.

Comment: _love_ is a concept, _woman_ is not.

Comment: _Woman_ is used as an(abstract) concept, are you saying you decide what an author is allowed to use conceptually, and what not? Is the sentence _all of man's creations_ "wrong" because _man_ is not a "concept" to you?

Comment: It's called [**poetic license**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license), poets and song writers deliberately bend "grammar rules" in order to achieve rhyme, metre, alliteration etc.

Comment: The pronunciation of *women* /wɪmɪn/ is quite different from *woman* /wʊmən/, try singing the line with *women* and see if it has the same effect. Slade, the 70s pop group, were hardly scholars or pedantic grammarians. They were a glam rock band.

Comment: While I'm late to the party, I believe the line should be "I believe in Woman", and keeping this in mind may make things clearer.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I don't understand. Why uppercase? Do you think it's a name?

Comment: @Pida - No, it's to mark the intent to refer to a generalized or idealized concept, rather than a specific individual.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Your interpretation is consistent with most what has been written before, but could you please explain the connection between capitalization this reading?

Comment: It's actually a somewhat archaic or overtly literary usage. I only suggested it in light of the comments to oerkelens answer. There exists what we might call a hierarchy of article definiteness. "The woman" and "The women" are extremely definite. "A woman" and "women" are less definite, and "woman" is the least definite and most general. And the discussion seemed to ignore this. Capitalizing "Woman", I thought, would make the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Woman* is the abstract representation of a phenomenon, not a reference to any specific individual female of the human species.

Ok, that sentence isn't going to enlighten anyone much, is it?

If one claims they believe in *fairies*, or *unicorns*, it means that they believe these creatures exist. In the case of unicorns or fairies, this is indeed something that necessitates *belief* because there has been, so far, little actual proof that they actually exist.

On the other hand, believing in (the existence of) *women* seems absurd — there is no belief involved, nobody will deny that they exist (unless you have grown up and spent your entire live surrounded by men, and “women” are as mythical as unicorns of course).

Apart from a believe in *existence*, the verb *believe* can also express a more abstract feeling: a trust in the power, possibilities, skills or capabilities of something or someone.

On the esoteric level, this is expressed as a *belief* in “(the power of) love”, a belief in “the good in people”.

More down to earth, one can express belief in another person. If I tell a friend that I believe in him, I do not mean I am convinced that he actually exists! I mean that I think he can do what he wants or needs to do. I believe he has the capability to succeed.

The line from the song is somewhere in between those two: the author expresses a confidence in the power and capabilities of women in and of womanhood. He doesn't express any feeling about any specific individual person, but he treats "woman" as a more abstract description of femininity or, if you like, a symbol for all women in the world.

This is a contrast with the use of *man* to indicate humanity, nowadays including man *and* women: if we talk about *the world of man* or *man's creations*, we (nowadays) assume *man* to symbolise humans.

Comment: Can you explain why it's _believe in woman_ and not _believe in women_? The latter sounds more normal, having the same structure as _believe in fairies_ (you wouldn't say _believe in fairy_).

Comment: A belief in _women_ would mean, like with the fairies, that you believe that women exist. I _doubt_ the author wants to tell the world he believes that women exist. It is about as informative a statement as saying "I believe that apples exist", isn't it?

Comment: I understand that point. Can you explain why it's appropriate to use the singular form for what he's trying to express? I.e. why does _I believe in woman_ mean _I believe in femininity_?

Comment: Alternatively, an expressed belief in _women_ could mean that the author believes in the power to succeed of some specific women in in his life — it would need a lot of context though...

Comment: _femininity_ is just one of the aspects I assume is included in the concept "woman". _Humanity_ could be another aspect. What the author includes in the concept is ultimately up for interpretation of course. The concept of "Man" can in some cases exclude women. It can mean "human" as opposed to divine, or it can mean "human" as the creator of the actual society we live in. All possibilities that are dependent on context. I could believe in apple pie — but I would need context to explain what aspects of apple pie I put my faith in. Might be the power of apple pie to make people feel good.

Comment: Surely, according to your reasoning (trust, skill, capabilities etc.) the most logical and idiomatic phrase is "I believe in man". Man represents everyone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: it seems the author specifically wants to indicate such a belief about women, not including men. Maybe the author feels that by using _man_, a lot of people may not understand his commitment to the importance of women in this world. Maybe the author wants to express a specific opinion or point of view and has chosen these words to do that. I would not dare suggest his wording should be changed or is in any way poor.

Comment: @oerkelens, so why do you think the author chose *woman* instead of *women*? *women* is both an abstract description of femininity and a symbol for all women in the world **and** it's common English. If this was a recent song, I could imagine it's wording to be a feminist reaction to the generic use of *man*. But the song is from 1983...

Comment: @Pida: _Women_ is common, but _not_ commonly understood in an abstract way. Believing in _women_ means you believe they exist. That is absurd, and yes, I am quite sure the author did not want to make such an absurd statement. As for feminist ideas, it may be of interest to you that feminism is not something new. On the contrary, the western world experienced a militant feminist wave during the 1970's. So that someone in 1983 seemed to be aware of feminist discourse seems no more than likely.

Comment: I'd like to hear opinions by other native speakers on their interpretation of *to believe in women*. In my case (German native speaker!) , the fact that women obviously exist triggers the power/possibilities/skills interpretation even when the plural is used. -- I'm aware that feminism isn't that new, but is this explanation plausible? We're talking about mainstream culture. During the 70's/80's, Slade was really big in the UK and this song was one of their greatest hits.

Comment: @Pida, feminism _was_ mainstream in the 70's, so references to it in mainstream culture are not so strange.

Comment: Remember Jurassic Park? Dr. Ian Malcolm: “God creates dinosaurs. God destroys dinosaurs. God creates man. Man destroys God. Man creates dinosaurs.” — Dr. Ellie Sattler: “Dinosaurs eat man … woman inherits Earth.” She could well have added “I'm rooting for woman here” or something to that effect.

Comment: I realized that in German there's a tendency to use a definite article with plural nouns to express the power/possibilities/skills interpretation in such constructions - but only if the noun refers to something in the real world:  *Ich glaube an __ Einhörner* ('I believe in __ unicorns'), but *Ich glaube an* **die** *Frauen* ('I believe in **the** woman'). I don't know whether this observation holds for English as well, but however: It shows there can actually be grammatical differences depending on whether the referent(s) exists or not. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, *woman* stands in for *[womankind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/womankind)*

> Women considered collectively:
>   *a giant step forward for womankind*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

While not the most common construction, it connotes belief in the essence of the gender rather than any one representative or group of individuals.

**Supplement**

Use of *[woman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/woman)* (singular) can mean

> [IN SINGULAR] Female adults in general:
>   *woman is intuitive*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Similarly, *Collins* offers one definition of *[woman](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/woman)* (singular) as

> women collectively; womankind

The choice between *woman, women* and *womankind* is stylistic.

Comment: Thanks, but the question remains **why** the singular is used.